# siunitx: Number too big

Tags: siunitx

Given the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[scientific-notation = fixed, fixed-exponent = 0]{siunitx}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
   \SI{1e11}{\kg}
\end{document}
```

I get

```
./test.tex:9: Number too big.
<argument> 10000000000

l.9  \SI{1e11}{\kg}

 *File List*
 siunitx.sty    2016/03/01 v2.6q A comprehensive (SI) units package
   expl3.sty    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 programming layer 
siunitx-abbreviations.cfg    2016/03/01 v2.6q siunitx: Abbreviated units
 ***********
```

However, in [this related post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269448/siunitx-produces-number-too-big-error-with-large-numbers), the accepted answer says that the problem was fixed in `siunitx` v2.6l (2015/09/14).

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was due to a [bug in `siunitx`](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/301) which is fixed in [v2.7b, release data 2017-01-28](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/releases/tag/v2.7b).